# Finding the set of values so all roots of the equation are real numbers

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

Find the set he set of all values ​​of $\alpha, α ∈ (-π/2 ,π/2)$ such that all solutions of $x^4-2x^2+ \tan(α)=0$ are real numbers.

This question was first asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735257/idk-how-to-define-the-%CE%B1-values) by a friend of mine, but he's new to the site and is not really aware of all the rules (I am helping him with that), so I am asking this here with more details. We are both high school students and this problem was adapted from an entrance exam we are studying for.

This is his work:

$0 \le (x^2-1)^2$

$(x^2-1)^2 + \tan(\alpha) = 1\implies \tan(\alpha) \le 1\implies \alpha \in \left[-\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right]$

This is my work:

$y^2 - 2y + \tan(\alpha) = 0$

$y = \dfrac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4\tan(\alpha)}}{2}$

$4 - 4\tan(\alpha) \geq 0$

$\tan(\alpha) \geq 1 \implies \alpha \in \left[-\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right]$

Basically, we both got the same answers in different ways, but the problem says the answer is actually $\alpha \in \left[0, \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right]$, and it gives no explanation. We cannot find any mistakes in our work. Could anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: If you plug in $\alpha=-\pi/4$ you will see that the polynomial will have complex roots. The main issue is that $y=x^2$, so $y$ has to be non-negative.

Comment: @JackyChong Wait, I think I just realized: if $\tan(\alpha) < 0$, then $4 \tan(\alpha) > 4$, so $y$ could be a negative value and then $x$ is going to be a complex number. Is this right? I think this is what we were missing! Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yes. You are on the right track.

Comment: @JackyChong Thank you a lot! So our mistake was really simple. I'm goint to answer the question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, when $\tan(\alpha) < 0$, then $\sqrt{4 - 4 \tan(\alpha)} > 2$, so $y^2 - 2y + \tan(\alpha) = 0$ will have a positive and a negative solution, thus when we plug the negative solution back into $y = x^2$, $x$ will be a complex number. Hence $\tan(\alpha) \geq 0$ and so the set is $\left[0, \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

You could have avoided the problem computing the discriminant of the quartic equation (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots)).

$$\Delta=256 \,(\tan (\alpha )-1)^2 \,\tan (\alpha )$$

Quoting Wikipedia :

*"If $\Delta < 0$ then the equation has two distinct real roots and two complex conjugate non-real roots"*.

Then, the result since the sign of $\Delta$ is the sign of  $\tan (\alpha )$.

Comment: This is also really nice, we do not study the quartic equation in school so we did not know about the discriminant. Thank you.

Comment: @Ingrid. Most of the time, we do not use it but, in this case, the coefficients are so simple ! Cheers :-)